# retrofit call on object that contains another object represented by an array

Tags: java, json, object, retrofit

I have json data :

```
[
  {
    "RouteNo": "004",
    "RouteName": "POWELL/DOWNTOWN/UBC",
    "Direction": "WEST",
    "Schedules": [
       {
        "Destination": "UBC",
        "ExpectedCountdown": -4,
       },
       {
        "Destination": "Downtown",
        "ExpectedCountdown": -6,
       }
    ]
  },
  {
    "RouteNo": "006",
    "RouteName": "Grange str",
    "Direction": "South",
    "Schedules": [
       {
        "Destination": "Victoria",
        "ExpectedCountdown": -9,
       },
       {
        "Destination": "College station",
        "ExpectedCountdown": -15,
       }
    ]
   }
]
```

And I have my model Route.java:

```
public class Route {
    public String getRouteNo() {
        return RouteNo;
    }

    public void setRouteNo(String routeNo) {
        RouteNo = routeNo;
    }

    public String getRouteName() {
        return RouteName;
    }

    public void setRouteName(String routeName) {
        RouteName = routeName;
    }


    public Route(String routeNo, String routeName) {
        RouteNo = routeNo;
        RouteName = routeName;

    }

    private String RouteNo;
    private String RouteName;


}
```

My question is how should I insert Schedules object you can see in json data into Route model? I am confused in terms of (as far as I understood) it is an object containing an array and I am not sure how to represent it in this case. And how actually get the data from it in retrofit call? I need to get each destination for each route.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946453/retrofit-how-to-parse-a-json-array-that-combines-an-array-and-an-object

Comment: It's a `List` of `Schedule` entities.  You'll just have to create a `Schedule` class with the correct properties and add `private List<Schedule> schedules'` to your `Route` Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `Route` to be:

```
public class Route {
    public String getRouteNo() {
        return RouteNo;
    }

    public void setRouteNo(String routeNo) {
        RouteNo = routeNo;
    }

    public String getRouteName() {
        return RouteName;
    }

    public void setRouteName(String routeName) {
        RouteName = routeName;
    }


    public Route(String routeNo, String routeName) {
        RouteNo = routeNo;
        RouteName = routeName;

    }

    private String RouteNo;
    private String RouteName;

    private List<Schedule> schedules;  // add mutators with @JsonProperty annotation

}
```

Then create the `Schedule` class as described by the above JSON