# Retrofit - parsing json without SerializedName

Tags: android, api, gson, retrofit

I have an external web service that returns unnamed `json` like this;

```
[
  {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 1,
    "per_page": "310",
    "total": 304
  },
  [
    {
      "id": "ABW",
      "iso2Code": "AW",
      "name": "Aruba",
      "region": {
        "id": "LCN",
        "iso2code": "ZJ",
        "value": "Latin America & Caribbean "
      },
      "adminregion": {
        "id": "",
        "iso2code": "",
        "value": ""
      },
      "incomeLevel": {
        "id": "HIC",
        "iso2code": "XD",
        "value": "High income"
      },
      "lendingType": {
        "id": "LNX",
        "iso2code": "XX",
        "value": "Not classified"
      },
      "capitalCity": "Oranjestad",
      "longitude": "-70.0167",
      "latitude": "12.5167"
    },
    {
      "id": "AFG",
      "iso2Code": "AF",
      "name": "Afghanistan",
      "region": {
        "id": "SAS",
        "iso2code": "8S",
        "value": "South Asia"
      },
      "adminregion": {
        "id": "SAS",
        "iso2code": "8S",
        "value": "South Asia"
      },
      "incomeLevel": {
        "id": "LIC",
        "iso2code": "XM",
        "value": "Low income"
      },
      "lendingType": {
        "id": "IDX",
        "iso2code": "XI",
        "value": "IDA"
      },
      "capitalCity": "Kabul",
      "longitude": "69.1761",
      "latitude": "34.5228"
    }
  ]
]
```

I have  *CountriesResponse* class:

```
public class CountriesResponse {
    private ResponseDetails responseDetails;
    private List<Country> countries;
```

*ResponseDetails*:

```
class ResponseDetails {
    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    private int page;
    @SerializedName("pages")
    @Expose
    private int pages;
    @SerializedName("per_page")
    @Expose
    private String perPage;
    @SerializedName("total")
    @Expose
    private int total;
```

*Country*:

```
public class Country {
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("capitalCity")
    private String capital;
```

and the *ApiInterface*

```
public interface ApiInterface {
//http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries/all?per_page=310&format=json
    @GET("countries/all")
    Call<ArrayList<Country>> getCountries(@Query("per_page") int per_page, @Query("format") String format);
}
```

In the `CountriesResponse` class, I assume I am to annotate the properties with `@SerializedName`. How do i parse the `json` seeing that the objects and arrays in the `json` have no names.

Comment: your service does not return an arraylist of Country (which is what you declare in your api interface). It returns an array where the first object is a response details, and the second object is an array of country.

Comment: @njzk2, I tried editing the code, but the site won't let me save the edit. Says the question is mainly code.

But ignoring that mistake, how would I go about achieving my aim?

Comment: @ylinkz I updated my answer fully.  You should be able to accomplish it with this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your Call is returning the wrong type.  It should return the top level object `CountriesResponse` which you have holding a `ResponseDetails` because you want to get back all the json so you can parse out the anonymous elements.

2) In `CountriesResponse` you have a `List<Country>.` Annotations for serialization cannot be used in `Country` since there is no name there to match. This must be manually deserialized. So get rid of `@SerializedName` in Country for both fields.

3) Add a custom deserializer using Gson, see here: [Retrofit: how to parse a JSON array that combines an array and an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946453/retrofit-how-to-parse-a-json-array-that-combines-an-array-and-an-object)

You will need to parse the top level JSON element as an array with 2 elements in your deserialize code:

```
    final JsonArray jsonArray = json.getAsJsonArray();
    JsonObject rd = jsonArray get(0); //this is the ResponseDetails object
    CountriesResponse cr = new CountriesResponse();
    cr.setResponseDetails(rd);
    JsonArray countries = jsonArray.get(1) //<-- this is your List<Country>
    //now you must iterate list `countries`and create a new Country for each one then add it to the List<Country> in CountriesResponse
```

To see the structure clearly you can use https://jsoneditoronline.org and put your JSON there.
[image: your JSON]

Your Deserializer would look like:

```
public class MyDeserializer
    implements JsonDeserializer<CountriesResponse> {
  @Override
  public CountriesResponse deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException {
        final JsonArray jsonArray = json.getAsJsonArray();
        JsonObject rdObject =jsonArray get(0); //this is the ResponseDetails object
        CountriesResponse cr = new CountriesResponse();
        ///you might get this part for free with Retrofit since it is the top level object and JSON is expected as array of obj by default
        ////but if you did it manually it would look like:
        ResponseDetails rd = new ResponseDetails();
        //... now iterate the rdObject , setting the fields
         ...
        cr.setResponseDetails(rd);

        List cList = new ArrayList();
        JsonArray arr = jsonArray.get(1); //<-- this is your List<Country>
        //now you must iterate list and create a new Country for each one then add it to the List<Country> and set it on your CountriesResponse
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject jo = arr.getJSONObject(i);
           Country c = new Country();
           c.setName(jo.get("name");
           ...  set the capitalCity the same way
           cList.add();
        }
        cr.setCountriesList(cList)

       ...  
       return cr;
}
```

Now you have cr.getCountriesList() to display your data.
The JSONElements may need casting but this is essentially what to do.  One thing Retrofit/POJO/JSON converters do not offer is anonymous element support.

You will also need a TypeConverter for the List if you need to persist it with Room.

Comment: I wasn't the one that downvoted your answer. But it doest solve my problem. Thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: Tell me what part you have trouble with. I edited the answer with another link that more clearly shows you what to do.

Comment: Thanks for the great and detailed answer